# JTree, setUserObject(), toString()

Tags: java, swing, jtree, defaultmutabletreenode

What I'm trying to do is pretty simple, but running into some issues. I have a class and I`m overriding toString() with some value.

```
public class AClass {

@Override
public String toString() {
    int rand = 5 + (int) (Math.random() * 25);
    return Integer.toString(rand);
    }
}
```

I have a JTree and I`m adding the class object to the node by using setUserObject(). The display on the node now has the value from toString().

```
            DefaultMutableTreeNode  node = new DefaultMutableTreeNode();
            node.setUserObject(new AClass());
            fileTreeModel.insertNodeInto(node, (DefaultMutableTreeNode) rootNode, 0);
            tree.setSelectionPath(new TreePath(fileTreeModel.getPathToRoot(node)));
            tree.expandPath(new TreePath(rootNode.getPath()));
```

But, when I click on the nodes or try to add a new node, the toString() values are changing.

What`s going on here? Any help is greatly appreciated. 
Here is some sample code.

Main.java

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JDesktopPane;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JSplitPane;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;

import javax.swing.JTree;
import javax.swing.tree.DefaultMutableTreeNode;
import javax.swing.tree.DefaultTreeModel;
import javax.swing.tree.TreePath;
import javax.swing.tree.TreeSelectionModel;

import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

import javax.swing.JScrollPane;


public class Main {

private JFrame frame;
private JTree tree;
private DefaultMutableTreeNode rootNode ;
private DefaultTreeModel fileTreeModel;

/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                Main window = new Main();
                window.frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Create the application.
 */
public Main() {
    initialize();
}

/**
 * Initialize the contents of the frame.
 */
private void initialize() {
    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    JSplitPane splitPane = new JSplitPane();
    splitPane.setResizeWeight(0.2);
    frame.getContentPane().add(splitPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
    splitPane.setLeftComponent(scrollPane);

    tree = new JTree();
    tree.setBackground(new Color(255, 235, 205));
    scrollPane.setViewportView(tree);
    rootNode = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Files");
    fileTreeModel = new DefaultTreeModel(rootNode);
    tree.setModel(fileTreeModel);
    tree.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(
            TreeSelectionModel.SINGLE_TREE_SELECTION);
    tree.setRootVisible(true);

    JDesktopPane desktopPane = new JDesktopPane();
    desktopPane.setBackground(new Color(255, 255, 0));
    splitPane.setRightComponent(desktopPane);

    JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("New button");
    btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            DefaultMutableTreeNode  node = new DefaultMutableTreeNode();
            node.setUserObject(new AClass());
            fileTreeModel.insertNodeInto(node, (DefaultMutableTreeNode) rootNode, 0);
            tree.setSelectionPath(new TreePath(fileTreeModel.getPathToRoot(node)));
            tree.expandPath(new TreePath(rootNode.getPath()));
        }
    });
    btnNewButton.setBounds(122, 115, 89, 23);
    desktopPane.add(btnNewButton);

    }

}
```

AClass.java

```
public class AClass {

@Override
public String toString() {
    int rand = 5 + (int) (Math.random() * 25);
    return Integer.toString(rand);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4):

They are changing because each time `toString` is called you are calculating a new random number...

```
public String toString() {
    int rand = 5 + (int) (Math.random() * 25);
    return Integer.toString(rand);
}
```

So, each time the table updates, in response to, let's say, you clicking on them, or modifying the `TreeModel` in some way, the tree asks each node for it's value, which returns a new random number.

Try pre-calculating the value upfront.

```
node.setUserObject(new AClass(5 + (int) (Math.random() * 25)));
```

Then simply return this value...

```
public String toString() {
    return Integer.toString(rand);
}
```

Comment: Got it. Thanks MadProgrammer. The necessary changes have been made and the behavior understood.